# How to indent 2 characters and let shiftwidth unchanged to 1 character?

Tags: vim, indentation

I noted that ***shiftwidth*** is used to indent text.

This is my shiftwidth setting in _vimrc:

```
set shiftwidth=1
```

I don't want to change it. I use it for other functions.

But... I want to ***indent*** with 2 spaces like this:

```
--function-myfunction()
----1st-block
------2nd-block
--------3rd-block
--------end3rd-block
------end2nd-block
----end1st-block
--endfunction

- = 1 space
```

Is this possible?

This are my indent settings in _vimrc:

```
set autoindent  
set cindent  
set cinkeys=!^F
```

Comment: You could try Ctrl+V to get column visual select at the beginning of the lines, then inserting two spaces will indent everything. 1. move to beginning of line and ctrl_v 2. "I2 " then hit enter.

Comment: @ostler.c: I believe that would be Ctrl+V, followed by movement to select the appropriate lines, followed by 2I<Space><Esc> (the letter after 2 is capital I).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `setlocal`, for example:

```
:setl sw=2
```

It doesn't change global settings.

Comment: Kev, I use p.e. in the same files I indent the code "move selection right" (`>>`)and "move selection left" (`<<`). This moves the selection 2 spaces with your solution. Is there no way to use sw=1 (default) for moving selections and other functions and sw=2 only for indent?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a very elegant solution. But you can add this to your .vimrc and use `,>>` to indent to the right by 2. `>>` should still indent the normal (1) that you expect.

```
com! SpecialIndent call SpecialInd()
nmap <silent> ,>> :SpecialInd<CR>
function! SpecialInd(...)
    let s:special_indent=&sw
    setl sw=2
    silent exec "normal! >>"
    silent exec "setl sw=".s:special_indent
endfunction
```

Comment: Ostler c., I don't mean indent a block of text 2 spaces to the right but to indent a whole function. (see the many "-" in my question). I use the '=' to indent.